# Necesito solucionar un problema de Django - manage.py createsuperuser | UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Al ejecutar:

```
(env) luis@ux-pc:~/projects/administrador-webapp-django$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Nombre de usuario (leave blank to use 'luis'): superusername
```

Se me sale un error de Unicode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 38
1, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 37
5, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, i
n run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/crea
tesuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, i
n execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/crea
tesuperuser.py", line 140, in handle
    input_value = self.get_input_data(field, message)
  File "/home/luis/projects/administrador-webapp-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/crea
tesuperuser.py", line 195, in get_input_data
    raw_value = input(message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Esto pasa cuando intento crear un usuario, he buscado el UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128) y no he dado con el problema

Si alguno le ha pasado y lo ha solucionado, pido que porfavor me compartan la solucion, necesito avanzar en el proyecto que tengo.

Comment: esto ocurre cuando pones algun nombre de usuario en especifico ?

Comment: Es posible que estés poniendo tildes en tu nombre de superusuario ? O estás poniendo literalmente `superusername`?

Comment: a lo mejor `superusername``sea una palabra reservada de python y por eso no te deja, prueba con nombre

Comment: En mi caso lo solucioné cambiando de terminal. En la terminal de visualcode me daba error pero en gnome terminal no. Prueba cambiando de terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba colocando esta linea en los archivos ".py" de tu proyecto django como el "manage.py" y "settings.py".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

verifica previamente que tengas las migraciones

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Ese comentario sólo sirve para decirle a python el _encoding_ del fichero fuente (y no hace falta en Python 3 porque asume por defecto utf8). El problema del usuario no está ahí, sino en el _encoding_ de la entrada estándar.

Answer (score 1):

En el *stacktrace* que muestras puede verse en las última líneas (que son por donde hay que empezar a descifrar el error):

```
    raw_value = input(message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

La última línea indica el problema (al intentar decodificar un byte de valor `f3` como ascii, no ha sido capaz, lo que es normal porque ascii no tiene códigos tan altos, siendo el último el `7f`).

La línea anterior te indica en qué momento de tu código fuente surgió el problema y podemos ver que fue al hacer un `input()`. Éste lee de la entrada estándar lo que teclee el usuario, y por lo visto entre lo tecleado había un byte de valor `f3` que no es ascii válido.

El hecho de que aparezca un byte de valor `f3` me hace sospechar que tu encoding sea cp1252 (el de windows), o ISO-8859-1  o ISO-8899-15 (también conocidos como latin1 y latin9, respectivamente, típicos en versiones antiguas de Linux ya que las modernas usan utf8). Estos encodings que acabo de mencionar tienen todos ellos en la posición `f3` el caracter `ó` (o con tilde).

Habitualmente python auto-detecta el encoding usado por la entrada estándar, pero se ve que en tu caso ha fallado pues (según mi hipótesis) la entrada estándar sigue uno de los encodings que mencioné, y python en cambio cree que es ascii.

A veces esto pasa si la entrada estándar viene redireccionada de otro comando, a través de un pipe, como por ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero-datos.txt | python programa.py
```

En este caso python suele asumir que su entrada estándar es ascii, y fallar si lo que le llega del comando anterior contiene bytes no ascii.

Para estos casos en que la autodetección falla, puedes preparar una variable de entorno llamada `PYTHONIOENCODING` con el valor adecuado. En nuestro caso sería (suponiendo que `latin1` es el encoding realmente usado por la entrada estándar):

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=latin1
$ python programa.py
# o tambien
$ cat fichero.txt | python  programa.py
```